# partially update datatable in C#

Tags: c#, caching, datatable

I want to update datatable partially from cache so that only those rows which are modified since last caching will get updated. But don't know how to make partially update. Currently I am deleting whole datatable and then recache the whole one again.

Comment: Easy - simply update/overwrite the DataRows in the DataTable that have changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jeremy points out, it's easy to update individual rows or cells using `fnUpdate` (http://datatables.net/api), and you can use the Boolean arguments to prevent redrawing the whole datatable.

If you already know which data has changed then there's not much more to it.  If not, just call `fnGetData` with no arguments and iterate through the array of objects to compare. If you have any information on which column(s) are expected to change, this will perform much better than redrawing a large table.

It's worth mentioning that paginated tables showing fewer rows and tables using the scroller plugin (http://datatables.net/extras/scroller/) redraw very quickly.  It's possible that the user won't even perceive a blink.